# bitmap cannot defined the icon file

Tags: python, tkinter

I using bitmap funtion to decleare file of '.ico', but it's the same problem.
here is my code:

```python
class Login:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.master = window
        self.master.title("Login System")
        self.master.geometry("500x500+150+150")
        self.img = Image.open('loginImage.png')
        self.img.thumbnail((200, 200))
        self.new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.imgStudent = Label(self.master, image=self.new_img)
        self.imgStudent.pack()
        self.frameLogin = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameLogin.pack()
        self.labelUser = Label(self.frameLogin, text='Username', pady=10, padx=10, font=('tahoma', 10, 'bold'))
        self.labelUser.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.labelPass = Label(self.frameLogin, text='Password', pady=10, padx=10, font=('tahoma', 10, 'bold'))
        self.labelPass.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.username = Entry(self.frameLogin, font=('tahoma', 10, 'bold'))
        self.username.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.password = Entry(self.frameLogin, font=('tahoma', 10, 'bold'), show="*")
        self.password.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.LoginButton = Button(self.frameLogin, command=self.login, text='Login', font=('tahoma', 10, 'bold'),
                                  bg='#1b9ea4', fg='white', cursor='cross')
        self.LoginButton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='snew', pady=10, padx=10)

    def login(self):
            mydb = mc.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='',
            database='university'
            )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            sql = "select * from loginadmin where Username='" + self.username.get() + "' and Password='" + self.password.get() + "'"
            mycursor.execute(sql)
            res = mycursor.fetchone()
            if (res == None):
                mb.showerror('Failed Login', 'Invalid Username and Password ! please Try again')
            else:
                win = Toplevel()
                win.iconbitmap('swim_ring_icon_183313.ico')
                window = University(win)




if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    window = Tk()
    window.iconbitmap('swim_ring_icon_183313.ico')
    std = Login(window)

    mainloop()
```

here's fully error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\universitymanagementsystem-main\universitymanagementsystem-main\main.py", line 1019, in <module>
    window.iconbitmap('swim_ring_icon_183313.ico')
  File "C:\Users\Humam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2136, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "swim_ring_icon_183313.ico" not defined
```

i tried to use Image function and changing the photo format to `png`, still the same.

Comment: Use a full path to the .ico file rather than relying on it being found in the current directory.

Comment: i used this kind of path, and it's still the same: 'universitymanagementsystem-main/images/swim_ring_icon_183313.ico'

Comment: That should have been part of your question then, to prevent it from being a concern - it's a common problem.  And it's still possible that you didn't double up your backslashes so you didn't have a valid string.

Comment: can you please show me how it should be with backslashes

Comment: `'c:\\myprogram\\swim_ring_icon_183313.ico'`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be identified:

```
lang_python window.iconbitmap('images/swim_ring_icon_183313.ico')
```